# AS3 - Access a Number Type Variable From another class

Tags: actionscript-3

I have two classes, i want to access a variable or property of a class from a textfield of another class and update it on every frame.
here is the code of these two class. its very simple but as its my first project, it is giving problem. 
All i want is Simply Access level property if RoadRun.as Class from GametextField.as class

```
package
{
import flash.display.Graphics;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;

public class RoadRun extends MovieClip
{

    public var carHit:Boolean = false;
    public var roadWidth:Number;
    public var roadHeight:Number;
    public var speed:Number = .5;
    private  var  m_level:Number = 1;
    private var levelSpeed:Number= speed * level ;

    public function RoadRun()
    {
        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, added); 
    }

    private function added(event:Event):void
    {
        roadHeight = this.height;
        roadWidth = this.width;
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, move);  
    }


    private function move(event:Event):void
    {
        //trace(m_level);


        m_level = m_level + 0.1;
        if(carHit == false)
        {


            this.y += speed;
            speed++;
            if(speed >= 10)
            {
                speed = 10;             
            }


            if(this.y >= 400)
            {
                this.y = this.height - this.height - this.height; // this.y = 400;
            }

        }
        else if(carHit == true)
        {

                this.y += speed;
                this.speed -= .1;
                if(this.y >= 400)
                {
                    this.y = -400;
                }
                this.y = this.y;
                if(this.speed <= 0.0)
                {
                    speed = 0;
                }
        }

    }
    public function get level():Number
    {
        return this.m_level ;
    }
}
```

}

and then here i want it to be accessed.

```
package
{


import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.text.TextField;


public class GameTextField extends MovieClip
{

    public var score:Number = 0;
    private var road:RoadRun = new RoadRun();
    public  var level:Number;
    private var scoreField:TextField = new TextField();

    public function GameTextField()
    {   
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, added);              
    }


    private function added(event:Event):void
    {


            scoreField.background = true;
            scoreField.height = 20;
            scoreField.width = stage.stageWidth;
            scoreField.backgroundColor =  0x000000 ;
            scoreField.textColor = 0xFFFFFF;
            scoreField.y = 0;
            scoreField.x = 0;
            addChild(scoreField);
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);        
    }

    private function update(event:Event):void
    {       
            trace(road.level)

            scoreField.text = "Score = " + String(score) + "  Level = " + String(level)  ;              
    }
}
}
```

Well Everything is working Perfectly, But, Level is not Updating in GameTextField Class.
while its fine in RoadRun Class(i have chacked by trace() statement.
here the

!http://i1363.photobucket.com/albums/r711/fakhar121/GameScreen_zps75a4dc09.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is have a OOP approach, meaning use encapsulation in your classes. If you don;t know what that means, its ok. For instance, if you have a variable, that you want to be accessible, then you should really make it private, and the set up its own public function that returns the variable. Like this:

```
package {

public class SomeClass {
    private var someVar:Number = 12; // A private variable, which means only this class can
// use the reference someVar, and only other outiside classes can use the function getSomeVar.
    ... // skip some regular class stuff

    public function getSomeVar():Number {
        return this.someVar; //returns the variable someVar from this class to whoever is accessing it. 
//This function is public which means that anyone can call it and get the variable someVar.
    }
}
```

}

To access that variable, you just reference a class instance:

```
var someClass:SomeClass = new SomeClass(); // create the instance using the variable someClass
var myVar:Number = someClass.getSomeVar(); // ACCESSES the variable that you want from the class, 
//by first using the class instance reference, and then calling its public function that returns the value you want.
```

Also, you can use getter functions, this makes the function act as a variable, when it is not. For instance:

```
package {

public class SomeClass {
    private var  myVar:Number = 12;
    ...

    public function get someVar():Number { // The only difference here, is that
//this class is using a getter function (notice the get before the function name)
//to allow other sources to exclude the parentheses when calling this function, this
//way makes it so you can't pass any parameters,
//but that's ok because you don't need to when your only looking to access some data
//form the class.
        return this.myVar;
    }
}
```

}

You would reference the variable myVar from the class SomeClass by again, using a reference to a class instance, but this time, you exclude the parentheses, because the getting function is seen as a variable from outside the class.

```
var someClass:SomeClass = new SomeClass();
var myVar:Number = someClass.someVar;
```

This is the common way to handle data swapping between classes, because it is the most efficient. Below is what your RoadRun class should look with this technique (I only changed it so that i has a getter function for the variable that you want to be accessed by the other class, and m_level is changed because you cant have that variable have the same name as the getter function which is now level.)

```
package
{
import flash.display.Graphics;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;

public class RoadRun extends MovieClip
{
public var carHit:Boolean = false;
public var roadWidth:Number;
public var roadHeight:Number;
public var speed:Number = .5;
private  var  m_level:Number = 1; // this is the variable i want to access.
private var levelSpeed:Number= speed * level ;

public function RoadRun()
{
    this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, added); 
}

private function added(event:Event):void
{
    roadHeight = this.height;
    roadWidth = this.width;
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, move);  
}

private function move(event:Event):void
{

    level++;
    if(carHit == false)
    {


        this.y += speed;
        speed++;
        if(speed >= 10)
        {
            speed = 10;             
        }


        if(this.y >= 400)
        {
            this.y = this.height - this.height - this.height; // this.y = 400;
        }

    }
    else if(carHit == true)
    {

            this.y += speed;
            this.speed -= .1;
            if(this.y >= 400)
            {
                this.y = -400;
            }
            this.y = this.y;
            if(this.speed <= 0.0)
            {
                speed = 0;
            }
    }

}
public function get level():Number {
    return this.m_level;
}
```

}

Below is your other class, using the new way to get the level data.

```
package
{


import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.text.TextField;


 public class GameTextField extends MovieClip
{

    public var score:Number = 0;
    private var road:RoadRun = new RoadRun();
    private var level:Number;
    private var scoreField:TextField = new TextField();

    public function GameTextField()
    {   
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, added);              
    }


    private function added(event:Event):void
    {


            scoreField.background = true;
            scoreField.height = 20;
            scoreField.width = stage.stageWidth;
            scoreField.backgroundColor =  0x000000 ;
            scoreField.textColor = 0xFFFFFF;
            scoreField.y = 0;
            scoreField.x = 0;
            addChild(scoreField);
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);        
    }

    private function update(event:Event):void
    {       

            scoreField.text = "Score = " + String(score) + "  Level = " + String(road.level); // here, it is referencing it          
    }
}
```

}

Please, comment if you are confused or have any further questions.

Comment: ok, its good, i did something like that before, but my actual problem is (i think) logical, i mean i am getting logical error, i want my level(variable) to update on every frame, but it seems like my level(variable) is freeze on 1 and During Game in TextField  it only showing level = 1;(level not updating) even i am updating it in RoadRun class. (before first if statement) i have a screenshot of my game screen but i don't know how to post it here.

Comment: You can make an account on [PhotoBucket.com](photobucket.com) for free and upload a picture from your computer. Then you can go to that picture and Photobucket lets you copy the link, so that you can post it here (just edit your question and at the top, you can click image and read on how to insert it into your question) all you need is the link to your picture.

Comment: also, since I can't see anything wrong with the two classes that you have provided, I can't help you with figuring out the errors, but what I can do is strong recommend that you learn(if you have not already) all about the Flash Pro debugger because it is worth it. It tells you everything there is and could probably figure out this problem. But if not, then trace statements will also help you track this down.

Comment: oh, ok, Thanks, My Problem is solved by making static type variable.

Comment: You can do that, but if I was you, I would get to the bottom of the problem, so that in the future you don't make the same mistake again.

Answer (score 1):

```
private function update(event:Event):void
{       
    scoreField.text = "Score = " + String(score) + "  Level = " + String(level)
            + "  Speed = " + road.speed + "  Road Width = " + road.roadWidth;
}
```